# Draw single round cornered rectangle in word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, shapes

In word 2007, is there any single round cornered rectangle shape available (i.e ***only one corner as rounded***) ? or do we have to draw our own ?

Comment: isn't "Rounded rectangle" available as an option?

Comment: I want only one corner as rounded.

Comment: I have seen one link [Round same side corner rectangles in Powerpoint 2007 but not in word](http://help.wugnet.com/office/Round-side-corner-rectangles-Powerpoint-2007-Wo-ftopict1107045.html). I am not sure whether it is not correct or not, but in excel these shapes are available. Is there any chance to port them to word ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and No. But they can be copied from Excel and pasted into Word (where the corner to be rounded can be changed, etc).